# returning negative values

Tags: php

I have this very simple function...

```
function send_mail($to, $from, $from_mail, $subject, $message) {

  if ( empty($from) || empty($from_mail) || empty($subject) || empty($message) ) {
      return -1;
  }

  if ( isset ($_SESSION['last_mailed']) )
  {
    if ( $_SESSION['last_mailed'] + 180 < time() )
        return -2;
  }
  $_SESSION['last_mailed'] = time();

  if ( !validEmail($from_mail) )
     return -3;

  $from = strip_mail_headers_single($from);
  $from_mail = strip_mail_headers_single($from_mail);
  $subject = strip_mail_headers_single($subject);
  $message = strip_mail_headers_multi($message);

  return mail($to, $subject, $message, "From: $from <$from_mail>\r\n");

}

if ( !empty($_POST) ) {
  $result = send_mail($mail_to, $_POST['from'], $_POST['from_mail'], $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message']);

  if ( $result == -1 ) 
  {
      echo "<p>You need to complete all the fields.</p>";
  } 
  elseif ( $result == -2 ) 
  {
      echo "<p>You can only send one mail every three minutes.</p>";
  } 
  elseif ( $result == -3 ) 
  {
      echo "<p>Please enter a valid email address.</p>";
  } 
  else 
  {
      echo "<p>Mail sent successfully!</p>";
  }
}
```

I am getting some strange results.  The `mail()` function returns, result is set to 1 and the mail is sent.  However, "`if ( $result == -1 )`" evaluates to true for some reason and the corresponding error message is printed out. Why is this? Any ideas?

Comment: Does "if ( $result === -1 )" give the same result?

Comment: if(1 == 1) // true
if(1 == "1") // true
if(1 === 1) // true
if(1 === "1") // false

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're returning the result of `mail()`, which is `true` in the case of success, and PHP has this really stupid stuff going on where the semantics of `true` are that it's the same (in weak `==` comparison) as every boolean-true expression, including `-1`.

Recommendation:

```
return mail($to, $subject, $message, "From: $from <$from_mail>\r\n") ? 1 : 0;
```

and add handling for the `0` case indicating that `mail()` failed.

Comparing using `===` instead of `==` would also work.

Comment: Ah thanks.  Yeah, I'm a C programmer where returning ints is plain and simple.

Answer (score 3):

For starters your logic is wrong here:

```
if ( $_SESSION['last_mailed'] + 180 < time() )
    return -2;
}
$_SESSION['last_mailed'] = time();

// snip

elseif ( $result == -2 ) 
{
    echo "<p>You can only send one mail every three minutes.</p>";
}
```

This says in plain-English, if more than 3 minutes have elapsed since the last email was sent, then return -2.

Secondly the [mail function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) in PHP returns a bool true or false. Do not try to compare this to -1.

Comment: Thanks for that, you're right of course.  It's not my code. I got it from here - http://robm.me.uk/articles/sending-mail-with-php

Answer (score 0):

In the first line, where you're checking for empty values, you're forgetting to check `$to`

```
if ( empty($from) || empty($from_mail) || empty($subject) || empty($message) )
```

Which then skips that `if-condition` because, even if it's blank, you're not checking for it and so nothing's really wrong.

Then when you get to the `mail()` function, the email is successfully sent, regardless in this case of no `to` name and then returns the boolean value of `true` or `1`.

Additionally, because you're testing this:

```
if ($result == -1)
```

It will always evaluate to `true` because in the world of [PHP, boolean types](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) are `true` unless they're `false` or empty.

Change those checks to quoted, like so:

```
if ($result == "-1")
```

Comment: 0 is the other false condition.